# Proper syntax for navigation

Tags: html, syntax

Im on doubts which syntax to use for navigation looks like this.

[image]

I didnt created css file yet, but here is how this should work. For example if I click to link one in nav at the main content will be shown first element and so on, rest will be hidden.

Here is the [first variant](http://codepen.io/marciapn/pen/ojgrKb)

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <a href="first">First</a>
    <a href="hello">Hello</a>
    <a href="best">Best button ever</a>
</nav>  
<section>
  <p class"1">X</p>
  <p class"hello">Hello</p>
  <p class"best">Im the best p element of the world</p>
</section>
```

html code is simple and clean, but there is more work in css/javascript than on this second solution [here](http://codepen.io/marciapn/pen/bVNXbv)

```
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li>Show child
      <ul>
        <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
      </ul>  
    </li>

    <li>Show child
      <ul>
        <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
      </ul>  
    </li>

    <li>Show child
      <ul>
        <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
      </ul>  
    </li>
  </ul>  
</nav>
```

Which variant and why you will recomend me?

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the first example. For what you are trying to achieve this is entirely sufficient - the second example involves using nested `<ul>` lists which is completely unnecessary and involves a lot of extra mark-up, when all you need is a basic link element for each navigational item.